# CPLEX float precision

Tags: java, linear-programming, cplex

Question: How small can a float be before CPLEX sees it as 0?

I am asking this question because my ILP usually deals with small numbers however now it has encountered numbers of 10^-18 to 10^-35. And the results indicated that there was something wrong. Java didn't read or write them wrong and the next step is the CPLEX solving of the ILP so I am wondering how small the float can be.

More information: Without going into too much detail, my system uses a form of percentile relaxation to allow artificial variables to take over the work of the objective function variables, however it seems now that these artificial variables with no influence over the objective function are not picked over the objective function variables which do have a weight.

Comment: CPLEX will probably scale the problem so that your question is probably not only this, but also: how big can the gap be between my variables? Analyzing the results should be done with reading out status messages (you did not indicate how you came to your conclusion). Apart from that, most tolerances can be controlled by parameters i assume. But this is surely a complex topic.

Comment: CPLEX (and most other solvers) will behave best when they have numbers with a smaller range of values. For example, there are built-in tolerances inside CPLEX for feasibility and integrality that are typically 10^-5 or 10^-6. So if you have values in your model between 10^-18 and 10^-35, that covers 17 orders of magnitude, much wider than the default tolerances, so the smaller values will probably get lost in the noise. Are these very tiny values actually useful in your model, and do they affect the solution in meaningful ways? 10^18 is about the ratio of size between an atom and the planet.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick To answer your question yes these values are significant because they indicate the importance the lower the number the higher the importance and thus it should 'activate' these first. Atm it chooses them automatically because they are almost 0. Now that I have this range I can probably scale each of them to fit this range with lowest still being lowest etc. Thanks for the help! If you want to write this in an answer I'll accept it as solution as soon as I know it works.

Comment: You may have better luck if you try a rational LP solver, such as [SoPlex](http://soplex.zib.de/).